# Referencing a folder Java

Tags: java, directory

I need to reference a folder location in one of my projects so that I can recursively search through it when need be. I'm having a bit of trouble determining what the best variable to use for this would be. Every time I Google folder and Java I get information not relevant to what I need.

In this instance would I just declare the folder itself with the File variable, I'm assuming because it has a isDirectory() method it doesn't matter if the "file" itself is a folder or a file?

Comment: Yes, `File` can reference both files and directories. So, you would sort of do `if (folder.isDirectory()) File[] files = folder.listFiles();` where `folder` is a `File` reference denoting a directory and the returned `File[]` could again contain both files and directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use java.io.File to reference both file and directories. From [the Java SE 6 API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.